# Chinese keyboard not responding Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, ibus, chinese

Sometimes (it happens randomly), I press the right arrow to find other words and the search bar just closes even though the right arrow is white (it didn't even turn orange when I pressed it); it just completely disappears and i'm left with a phrase of Chinese (simplified) characters I didn't even want. Also, I would like to be able to select a Chinese character by just pressing it, instead of pressing the number that corresponds to it, that'd be a very nice feature (don't know if i'm asking this in the right place, but meh).

PS: i'm using ibus

Comment: also add output of lsusb

Comment: what do u mean?! is this supposed to solve my problem? can u specify?